# Add lines between two inline images in word

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I have a code to add inline images to word. Now if I want to add a line between them what shall I do ?

```
var WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();         
WordApp.Documents.Add();
WordApp.Visible = true;         
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = WordApp.ActiveDocument;
doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture("c:\\mypic1.jpeg");
doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture("c:\\20140203_202325.jpg");            
doc.SaveAs2("C:\\MyDocument.doc");            
WordApp.Quit(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

I tried with the following line , but that dint help..

```
WordApp.Selection.InsertAfter("\r\nThis is some random text");
```

What shall be the one to place a line between them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this piece of code :

That would add the image and then a line to it.

```
        object StartPos = 0;
        object Endpos = 1;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = doc.Range(ref StartPos, ref Endpos);
        object NewEndPos = rng.StoryLength - 1;
        rng = doc.Range(ref NewEndPos, ref NewEndPos);
        rng.Select();

        var pText = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
        pText.Format.SpaceAfter = 10f;
        pText.Range.Text = String.Format("This is line");
        pText.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

        object StartPos1 = 0;
        object Endpos1 = 1;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng1 = doc.Range(ref StartPos1, ref Endpos1);
        object NewEndPos1 = rng.StoryLength - 1;
        rng1 = doc.Range(ref NewEndPos, ref NewEndPos);
        rng1.Select();
        doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(loc +@"\" + dt + ".jpeg");
```

I hope this would help.